# Disable branding in vlc web plugin

Tags: web, plugins, vlc

Using the VLC web plugin for vlc 2.1.6 Ricewind on Ubuntu does not allow to disable the vlc logo, if no stream is playing. 
Here is the snippet which embeds vlc:

```
        <EMBED pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
               type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
               version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
               width="100%"
               windowless="false"
               height="100%"
               toolbar="false"
               text="Waiting for video"
               name="vlc_overlay_player"
               style="visibility: hidden"
               id="vlc_overlay_player"
               branding="false"
               >
        </EMBED>
```

How can I remove the VLC icon when no video is playing?

Comment: The branding option is only supported for [Mac](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/npapi-vlc/blob/master/NEWS#L87) since 2.2.0 and [Windows](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/npapi-vlc/blob/master/NEWS#L52) since 2.2.2.